# MySql - access denied, despite GRANT ALL

Tags: mysql

What am I doing wrong here?

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'demoUser'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE  
 WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0  
 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;

C:\Users\me>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe"   
  "--defaults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" -udemoUser -pitsAsecret

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'demoUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the password when granting privileges on that user. You should use something like:

```
GRANT ALL ON ... TO ... IDENTIFIED BY 'itsAsecret';
```

Comment: D'oh! How could I have missed that? Strangely, though, that command was generated by PhpMyAdmin - after the user had been created - with a password(!).